# Add ordinal information to date

Tags: javascript, html

Kinda new to JavaScript and am trying to add ordinal information to dates e.g Instead April 4 I want April 4th currently im just using the code below to get the date number, what would I add to get ordinal info

```
//Date
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDate();    
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = n;
```

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your code and any error messages!

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's just the rightmost two letters of the english phrase for that ordinal number.  Since you're only interested in numbers between 1 and 31 I'd just use the date as an index into an array:

```
var ordinalNames = [ "", "first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth", "seventh", "eighth", "ninth", "tenth", "eleventh", "twelfth", "thirteenth", "fourteenth", "fifteenth", "sixteenth", "seventeenth", "eighteenth", "nineteenth", "twentieth", "twenty-first", "twenty-second", "twenty-third", "twenty-fourth", "twenty-fifth", "twenty-sixth", "twenty-seventh", "twenty-eighth", "twenty-ninth", "thirtieth", "thirty-first" ];

var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDate();    
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = n + ordinalNames[n].slice(-2);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a pattern and you can make a function out of it

```
function nth(date) {
  if(date>=4 && date<=20) return 'th';
  switch (date % 10) {
        case 1:  return "st";
        case 2:  return "nd";
        case 3:  return "rd";
        default: return "th";
    }
}
```